# Normalize.min.css bugs my script jquery - scrollTotop

Tags: jquery, html, css

so this is my script to back to top

```
$(function(){
    $('.top').click(function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0},'slow');
    });
});
```

kind simple but works fine

the problem is, hes bug's with my normalize.min.css

in this part

```
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0
}
```

i dont' no why bugs with   overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 100%;

i really need a help or sugestions , and thanks for read - bye

(sorry for bad english -- from Brasil :D)

Comment: Are you 100% certain the CSS inside body{} (first declaration) causes the bug? What is the bug?

Comment: bugs the jquery animate  scrollTOtop

Comment: bugs with just css term  overflow-x: hidden;  if i remove the scroll jquery works fine , i just need to know why this happen, for fixed it